# How do I scroll-back in a virt-manager virtual machine console?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have been using virt-manager to manage a few KVM guests fruitfully on my computer so far. It's simple and quite viable.

Nevertheless, up to now, I haven't found a way to scroll back lines displayed in a virtual machine console.  I would like to have this ability in case a guest doesn't boot properly, I have a quicker way to nail down the cause.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a virtual terminal console TTY1... TTY7 we can scroll up/down a whole page (but not a single line) using the following key combination:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd>: scrolls back one page

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd>: scrolls down one page

Comment: this doesnt work for me using ubuntu cloud image 20.04 inside virt-manager