# How to enable scrolling in Virtual Machine?

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I am using a virtual Machine in VMware Player 5.01 of Ubuntu 12.04 without a graphical interface and I don't have scroll enabled is there any way to enable it ? Or to use something like a key combo to scroll up and down :)

Comment: You may try if this also works with VMWare Player: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197314/how-do-i-scroll-back-in-a-virt-manager-virtual-machine-console

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is<sup>1</sup>, but unless you have a valid reason to do so, don't even bother using the VMware Player window for command-line stuff. Set up networking and use SSH instead. It's way more powerful than using an hardware-emulated display and graphics driver just for some plain commands.

You might also be interested in using `byobu` (with or without using SSH):

- [How to open a new tab in the server command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/237099/88802)

  For related stuff to scrolling in command-line operations.
- [using a byobu and disconnected session how to see message on screen](https://askubuntu.com/a/237974/88802)

  which effectively is a question on how to scroll in Byobu.

A question on Unix&Linux very similar to yours:

- [small screen in virtualbox installed OSs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57541/23363)

  VirtualBox is not different from VMware regarding your question.

---

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>If you really insist on scrolling in a regular TTY (has many flaws): <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd></sub>

<sub>And copy/paste within the same TTY: `sudo apt-get install gpm` to get a mouse pointer.</sub>

<sub>But really, those two above are not for daily use!</sub>

Comment: If there was a third recipe in footnotes to set scroll limit to infinite that would have been a very informative footnote.